# Laravel tries to route media files after setting up SSL

Tags: php, apache, laravel, ssl, xampp

I have setup a self signed certicifate on XAMPP Apache and now Laravel tries to use all paths to media files as routes.

For instance

> http://example.com/media/business/1/asdqwe.jpg

Of course if it will gets routed by the framework it will throw an error, because I don't have such a route. My Apache.conf is below:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\example\public
    ServerName local.example.com
    ServerAlias *.local.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything worked fine before I have setup the HTTPS.